# How to re-trigger Completed pods of K8S CronJob if Running still exists?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

K8S Version: 1.23

I have an hourly CronJob with 5 inner pods. After some time, part of these pods goes to shutdown and moved to the `Completed` state (it's expected), but the rest - still works, so have a `Running` state.

At the next hour, this CronJob will not be triggered due to the `Running` pods (it's also expected). But I need to force recreate pods with the `Completed` state if a `Running` still exists. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the reason you're letting the `Running` pods exist is that you expect those pods to take a long time before finishing. This means that the scheduling of those pods *should* be different from others, since they can take a longer time to finish.

You can split your `CronJob` into two `CronJobs`. One of these will run every hour and will only have the pods that get `Completed`. The other will run less frequently (maybe every 2 hours?) allowing the `Running` pods to finish.

This way, you will be able to manage your `cron` tasks separately.

> Note: For k8s version, we usually mention the API version which is of the form `v1.xx`. It appears you are reporting the version of a public cloud offering of k8s like `AKS`, `EKS` or `GKE`. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer to my question. It is quite possible that CronJob is not suitable for my specific task. In any case, I gonna try to investigate the split solution, I think it will be more than enough.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped :) You can accept the answer once it proves to work for you, to others can also get help :)